# How to get array after adding a number to specific data of that array?

Tags: python, arrays, subtraction

```
import numpy as np 
import xlrd
import xlwt

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Scatter plot.xlsx')
workbook = xlwt.Workbook() 

sheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet1")

sh1 = wb.sheet_by_name('T180')
sh2=wb.sheet_by_name("T181")

x= np.array([sh1.col_values(1, start_rowx=51, end_rowx=315)])
y= np.array([sh1.col_values(2, start_rowx=51, end_rowx=315)])

x1= np.array([sh2.col_values(1, start_rowx=50, end_rowx=298)])
y1= np.array([sh2.col_values(2, start_rowx=50, end_rowx=298)])

condition = [(x1<=1000) & (x1>=0) ]
condition1 = [(y1<=1000) & (y1>=0) ]

x_prime=x1[condition]-150
y_prime= y[condition1]+20

plt.plot(x,y, "ro", label="T180")
plt.plot(x_prime,y_prime,"gs")
plt.show()
```

I want to subtract 150 from the values less than 1000 of x1 array and finally I need all values (subtracted+remaining). But with this code I got only the values that are less than 1000. But I need both (less than 1000+ greater than 1000). But greater than 1000 values will be unchanged. How can I will do this. As you can see there 248 elements in x1 array so after subtraction I will need 248 element as **x_prime**. Same as for y. Thanks in advance for your kind co-operation.

Comment: can you upload your Excel file somewhere and post here a link? It would help us to code and __test__ solutions...

Comment: I cannot upload it, I did not find anyway to upload this file. What can I do? Thanks for your kind concern.@MaxU

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=free+upload+file&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr#pws=0&gl=us&q=free+file+hosting

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/scatterplot           @MaxU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Pandas solution:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

fn = r'/path/to/ExcelFile.xlsx'
sheetname = 'T181'
df = pd.read_excel(fn, sheetname=sheetname, skiprows=47, parse_cols='B:C').dropna(how='any')

# customize X-values
df.ix[df.eval('0 <= GrvX <= 1000'), 'GrvX'] -= 150
df.ix[df.eval('2500 < GrvX <= 3000'), 'GrvX'] += 50
df.ix[df.eval('3000 < GrvX'), 'GrvX'] += 30

# customize Y-values
df.ix[df.eval('0 <= GrvY <= 1000'), 'GrvX'] += 20

df.plot.scatter(x='GrvX', y='GrvY', marker='s', s=30, label=sheetname, figsize=(14,12))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you bro. It shows error in fn. What to do? @MaxU

Comment: @QuaziNizam, sorry, `fn` - is a filename (including a path) - it's got lost. I've corrected my answer...

Comment: Thanks. One more problem, I want figure like this http://www.filedropper.com/figure2_1 , but according to your code I found like this: http://www.filedropper.com/figure3 How to solve?@MaxU

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. If I want more condition like -150 for <1000, and add 50 for values >2500,add 30 for >3000 of x1 (same as y1) what can I do? @MaxU

Comment: @QuaziNizam, you can do it similar to `df.ix[df.eval('0 <= GrvX <= 1000'), 'GrvX'] -= 150`...

Comment: @QuaziNizam, for square markers use this: `df.plot.scatter(x='GrvX', y='GrvY', marker='s', s=30, label=sheetname, figsize=(14,12))`

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. If I want more condition like -150 for <1000, and add 50 for values >2500,add 30 for >3000 of x1 (same as y1) what can I do? @MaxU

Comment: @QuaziNizam, please update your question accordingly - it's not clear: `If I want more condition like -150 for <1000, and add 50 for values >2500 ...`

Comment: How can I save these "df" values in excel file? @MaxU

Comment: @QuaziNizam, i think i have answered already your original question. Usually if you want to ask another question you should open a new topic...

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I`m going to do that@MaxU

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.place`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html) to modify arrays where a logic expression holds. For complex logic expressions on the array there are the [logic functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html) that combines boolean arrays.

E.g.:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
np.place(A, np.logical_and(A > 1, A <= 8), A-10)
```

will subtract `10` from every element of `A` that is `> 1` and `<= 8`. After this `A` will be

```
array([ 1, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3,  9, 10])
```

Comment: "ValueError: object too deep for desired array" it shows this kind of error for the following code:                                                                  z=np.place(x1, np.logical_and(x1 > 1, x1 <= 1000), x1-150)
print z @eistaa

Comment: @QuaziNizam I think the error comes because your `x1` is multidimensional. When you construct `x`, `y`, `x1`, and `y1` you have `[ ]` brackets around the `col_values` expression, this makes a list containing a slice, while you only want the slice. Try removing those brackets.

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. If I want more condition like -150 for <1000, and add 50 for values >25000,add 30 for >3000 of x1 (same as y1) what can I do?

Comment: @QuaziNizam use multiple `place` statements

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand. Would you please just show me the code as example. Thanks for your kind help. @eistaa

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
#random initialization
x1=np.random.randint(1,high=3000, size=10)

x_prime=x1.tolist()

for i in range(len(x_prime)):
    if(x_prime[i]<=1000 and x_prime[i]>=0): 
        x_prime[i]=x_prime[i]-150

x_prime=np.asarray(x_prime)
```

**Answer:**

```
x1
Out[151]: array([2285, 2243, 1716,  632, 2489, 2837, 2324, 2154,  562, 2508])

x_prime
Out[152]: array([2285, 2243, 1716,  482, 2489, 2837, 2324, 2154,  412, 2508])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows same result for x1 and x_prime. @ Sayali Sonawane

Comment: you will get same results, if you won't convert it into list first. This is why, I have converted it into list first. Then perform operations and convert back to array.